# Android : Parsing XML file but not getting access to more than one element through class object

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing

The xml file I am parsing is alltrains.xml is as follows

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <resources>
<train>
    <trainno>02018</trainno>
    <name>GKP LTT PREMIUM</name>
    <sourcestation>GORAKHPUR JN</sourcestation>
    <deptime>08:25</deptime>
    <destinationstation>LOKMANYATILAK T</destinationstation>
    <destarrtime>11:50</destarrtime>
</train>
<train>
    <trainno>02529</trainno>
    <name>GKP UHP PREMIUM</name>
    <sourcestation>GORAKHPUR JN</sourcestation>
    <deptime>20:55</deptime>
    <destinationstation>UDHAMPUR</destinationstation>
    <destarrtime>21:30</destarrtime>
</train>
<train>
    <trainno>02530</trainno>
    <name>UHP GKP PREMIUM</name>
    <sourcestation>UDHAMPUR</sourcestation>
    <deptime>23:45</deptime>
    <destinationstation>GORAKHPUR JN</destinationstation>
    <destarrtime>23:20</destarrtime>
</train>
<train>
    <trainno>02680</trainno>
    <name>SVDK YPR PREMIUM</name>
    <sourcestation>SHMATA VD KATRA</sourcestation>
    <deptime>06:30</deptime>
    <destinationstation>YESVANTPUR JN</destinationstation>
    <destarrtime>15:00</destarrtime>
</train>
<train>
    <trainno>02696</trainno>
    <name>JP YPR PREMIUM</name>
    <sourcestation>JAIPUR</sourcestation>
    <deptime>22:15</deptime>
    <destinationstation>YESVANTPUR JN</destinationstation>
    <destarrtime>17:55</destarrtime>
</train>
    </resources>
```

The code of MainActivity.java is as follows

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
static Resources myResources;
static InputStream inputStream;
TechCrunchTask downloadTask;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myResources = getResources();
    downloadTask=new TechCrunchTask();
    downloadTask.execute();
}

public static class TechCrunchTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>>
{
    @Override
    protected ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> doInBackground(Void... params)
    {
        ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> results=new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            inputStream = myResources.openRawResource(R.raw.alltrains);

            results=ProcessXml(inputStream);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return results;
    }
    @Override
    protected  void  onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> result)
    {
        // L.m(result+"");
    }

    public ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> ProcessXml (InputStream inputStream) throws  Exception
    {
        DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory=DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder documentBuilder=documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document xmlDocument=documentBuilder.parse(inputStream);
        Element RootElement=xmlDocument.getDocumentElement();
        Log.d("ResourceName",xmlDocument.getDocumentElement().toString());
        NodeList itemList=RootElement.getElementsByTagName("train");
        Node CurrentItem=null;
        NodeList ItemChildren=null;
        Node CurrentChild=null;
        NamedNodeMap MediaThumbnailAttributes=null;
        Node CurrentAttribute=null;
        int count=0;

        ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> results=new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0;i<itemList.getLength();i++)
        {
            CurrentItem=itemList.item(i);

            ItemChildren=CurrentItem.getChildNodes();
            for(int j=0;j<ItemChildren.getLength();j++)
            {
                TrainObject trainObject=new TrainObject();
                CurrentChild=ItemChildren.item(j);
                String name="";
                int id;
                trainObject.setId(i+1);
                Log.d("ID",Integer.toString(trainObject.getId()));
                if(CurrentChild.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("name"))
                {
                    name=CurrentChild.getTextContent();
                    // Log.d("Name",name);
                    trainObject.setTrainName(name);
                    Log.d("Name",trainObject.getTrainName());
                    Log.d("Object",""+Integer.toString(trainObject.getId())+":"+Integer.toString(trainObject.getTrainNo()));
                }
                if(CurrentChild.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("trainno"))
                {
                    id=Integer.parseInt(CurrentChild.getTextContent());
                    //Log.d("ID",Integer.toString(id));
                    trainObject.setTrainNo(id);
                    Log.d("Trainno",Integer.toString(trainObject.getTrainNo()));
                    Log.d("Object2",""+Integer.toString(trainObject.getId())+":"+Integer.toString(trainObject.getTrainNo())+":"+trainObject.getTrainName());
                }
            }
        }
        return results;
    }//End of ProcessXml Function
}
```

The code for TrainObject.java class is as follows

```
    package xml_parsing_slidev2.ats.com.xml_parsing_slidev2;
    public class TrainObject
    {
     int id;
     int TrainNo;
String TrainName;
public int getId()
{
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id)
{
    this.id = id;
}

public int getTrainNo()
{
    return TrainNo;
}

public void setTrainNo(int trainno)
{
    this.TrainNo = trainno;
}

public String getTrainName()
{
    return TrainName;
}

public void setTrainName(String trainName)
{
    this.TrainName = trainName;
}
   }
```

This code works fine if I am accessing the values of trainno and name in their own if blocks but if I access those collectively Like I tried to access with statement

```
 Log.d("Object2",""+Integer.toString(trainObject.getId())+":"+
    Integer.toString(trainObject.getTrainNo())+":"+trainObject.getTrainName());
```

it shows only Trainno and does not show train name rather it is
showing null value

Kindly guide me how I can get all values in one go so that I can pass same to my autocompleteTextView.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First mistake: You create the trainObject in every iteration on the fields again. So the instance of the iteration before is lost. Create it before the j-loop:

```
       TrainObject trainObject=new TrainObject();
        for(int j=0;j<ItemChildren.getLength();j++)
        {
            CurrentChild=ItemChildren.item(j);
```

Second: You cannot rely on ordering. In fact when I ran the program the second if was executed before the first. So the output "Object2" was done before the name even could be read. If you add an output after the end of the j-loop with all fields (like in the name-if) you should see all members assigned.

Comment: You are welcome. May I ask you to accept the answer, and probably upvote it?